# MS Access Date/Time printing differently in C#

Tags: c#, string, date, ms-access

I have an Microsoft Access database with a table which looks like this in design view:

```
Field Name |  Data Type
-----------+-------------
ID         | Number
Name       | Text
Birthday   | Date/Time
```

When you view the table in Access, the values look like this:

```
ID  Name   Birthday
----------------------
1   Jose   9/19/1948
2   Mark   10/1/2001
3   Cindy  3/14/1987
```

I imported the Access table to a C# `DataTable` object using OLEDB. When I go to print out the values, the dates display differently.

```
OleDbCommand selectTable = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM [Example]", conn);
// conn is my OLEDB connection object

OleDbDataReader oleReader = selectTable.ExecuteReader();

DataTable currentTable = new DataTable();

currentTable.Load(oleReader);

foreach (DataRow row in currentTable)
{
    foreach (DataColumns col in currentTable)
    {
        Console.Write(row[col].ToString().Trim().PadRight(10));
    }
    Console.Write("\r\n");
}
```

This prints out

```
1         Jose      9/19/1948 12:00:00 AM
2         Mark      10/1/2001 12:00:00 AM
3         Cindy     3/14/1987 12:00:00 AM
```

Which is weird. Especially because I determined that the longest text representation of the numeric date/time values has only 10 characters (using the accepted method [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22793072/get-maximum-length-of-datatable-column-character-representation), if it helps). Clearly the date values being written to the console have more than 10 characters. Can anyone provide some insight into what's going on here?

My goal is directly export the values from Access so that whatever value is stored in Access is what prints out. If a time portion is there I want to print it with the date and if not then I just want to print the date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's reading the date values as `DateTime` objects, which always contain a time component. When you print them, they are printing using the default `ToString()`. You can specify a format to print them any way you like (e.g., "MM/dd/yyyy").

Note that `PadRight` does not truncate at 10 characters, it pads up to ten characters.

Comment: I don't want to have to know whether there is a time component in the Access table in my C# program. Is there a way for me to use the raw value from Access (e.g. 9/19/1948) rather than having to format the date in C#? I'm trying for a direct export of the Access data.

Comment: Not really. Once you've read that in to your program, it's a `DateTime`, which always has a time component.

Comment: There is a data component and a presentation component. At the data component, the data is a `DateTime` object. Its your job, at the presentation component, to present this data in the format you want.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `ToShortDateString()` instead of `ToString()` to omitt the time.